# Quartz scheduler - disable automatic trigger removal after it fires the last time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

**What works now**

In my Java Spring Boot application I'm using Quartz Scheduler v2.2.2 (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) to dynamically schedule execution of a job. The job store is Quartz managed transactional one with Oracle DB configured. Works.

**What needs to work**

The triggers that "expired" (finished their last execution) are removed from the database by default. However what I need is that they stay persisted with a COMPLETED status. They should not fire any executions any more, but the Scheduler (http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html) object should be able to retrieve them. Is there a way to disable trigger automatic removal (even if it's a dirty hack)?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue. I want to be able to check the last time the Job was executed, which isn't possible when the expired trigger gets removed.

Comment: I have the same issue and still struggling to find a solution for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also need solution for this

Answer (score 0):

One idea crossed my mind which is to:

1. create the transaction on the job
2. load the relevant data into memory
3. execute required business via job
4. store relevant information, concretely the one loaded in step two, to some new DB table